# Gradle - Generating serializable classes with jaxb

Tags: java, serialization, build, gradle, jaxb

I'm using gradle as build tool and configuring jaxb plugin jacobono. Have the below entry in build.gradle file:

```
jaxb {
  bindingsDir = "src/main/resources/xjb"
  xjc {
   xsdDir = "src/main/resources/xsd"
   generatePackage = "some.package"
  }
}
```

under xjb directory, have binding.xml with the below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb      
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.1">
   <globalBindings>
     <serializable uid="1" />
   </globalBindings>
 </bindings>
```

Although the files are getting generated, none of them implements serializable interface as i have defined in binding xml. I doubt on the binding dir configurations.

Any advice will be much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the binding information to xsds, and it worked.

Not sure whether the plugin works properly with binging dir paramter as it didnt work even with absolute path.